# How to get the installed version of a module?

Tags: 8, updating

We have a "MyModule" module, which has a mymodule.install. 
Inside the file, there is mymodule_update_8001, 8002 ... etc.

How can I tell programmatically that on which version the module has at the moment?
I know where to find them in database (key_value table), but I would like to use a service instead, if that's possible.

**The closest I found:**

```
$update_hook_count = \Drupal::keyValue('system.schema')->get('mymodule');
```

This returns the update hook number.

Comment: You answered yourself: You are actually using a service. If you mean you want to use an injected dependency, you cannot, from a function.

Comment: Thank you! Am aware of that, I just pasted this way for the sake of simplicity. 
Should I separate the answer, so I could accept it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the global function `drupal_get_installed_schema_version()`:

```
$update_hook_count = drupal_get_installed_schema_version('mymodule');
```

Comment: Thank you!! I prefer the service approach tho. It's good to know it's using the same service.

Comment: No problem, the function uses the same service. The only difference is that it stores the result in a static variable. If someone ask again about a schema version in the same request, it is then prepared to deliver a very fast answer.

Comment: That's true, and cool stuff. Wondering when it could be a performance issue to ask for schema version so many times ^^

Comment: My guess is this would only happen if you run update.php.

Answer (score 1):

```
drush sql-query "SELECT schema_version FROM system WHERE name = 'mymodule';"
```

Comment: Probably this is the worst solution from clean and robust perspective, but it's simple.

Comment: Was useful for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

`drush php-eval "echo drupal_get_installed_schema_version('my_module');"`

From: https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/update-api/updating-database-schema-andor-data-in-drupal-8#s-useful-drush-commands-while-developing-your-hook-update-n

Answer (score 1):

I came here to find a version of module but this question is actually about getting module's database schema version.
So here is a way to get only module version:

```php
$version = \Drupal::service("extension.list.module")->getExtensionInfo('mymodule')['version'] ?? 0;
```

And if you need later compare version:

```php
$affectedVersion = version_compare($version, '1.3.0', '>=');
```

Answer (score 0):

The Ivan Chaer's answer is deprecated due to database changes. Update below:

```
drush sql-query "SELECT CONVERT(value USING utf8) FROM key_value WHERE name = 'mymodule'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Drupal versions 9 and above would work with `\Drupal::service('update.update_hook_registry')->getInstalledVersion('MODULE_NAME');`.

See [this](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21schema.inc/function/drupal_get_installed_schema_version/9) for more information.